# Creating pie chart from given percentage, not values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

When I print the following pct_tested, I get a nicely displayed percentage (for example 27.83%) which corresponds to the percentage of tested elements to total elements.

```
pct_tested = "{:.2%}".format(number_of_tested/len(df.index))
```

Now, I want to create a pie chart where I input this `pct_tested` as the value and it outputs a pie chart with a slice = 27.83% and the other slice is the remainder (so 72.17%).

My trial:

```
plt.pie([pct_tested], colors = colors, autopct='%.2f%%')
```

Does not work because "%" is present in the value of pct_tested.

So I tried again with a purely numerical value just to see if that would fix it.

```
plt.pie([number_of_tested], colors = colors, autopct='%.2f%%')
```

This worked to create a pie chart, however, the outcome is simply a one slice pie chart with written 100% on it.

Then I realised that for my data I could simply use `[pct_tested, 100-pct_tested]` but I still run in the problem that it doesn't work because the value is not purely numerical, how can I fix it?

I am new to coding and realise this is quite a trivial request but I am not sure where to go from here, I simply need a bit of guidance. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a list of numbers with one value for each slice to `plt.pie`. There are a couple of ways to do this given the information you have.

1. Using the `pct_tested` value, you can calculate the other percentage by subtracting from 100.

   ```
    plt.pie([pct_tested, 100-pct_tested], autopct='%.2f%%')
   ```
2. Using the `number_of_tested` value, you can calculate the other value by subtracting from the total. I'll assume that total is `len(df.index)`, since you divided by that to get the `pct_tested` value.

   ```
    plt.pie([number_of_tested, len(df.index)-number_of_tested], autopct='%.2f%%')
   ```

Either one of those should give you a pie chart with two sections.

Comment: Option 1 is what I tried doing but I get this error 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'' I think this is because pct_tested literally outputs 27.83%, with the percent sign.. Or is the issue something else?

Comment: @BostonCo Yes, that's because it's a string. If you calculate the value as a number instead it will work. Remove the formatting and do `pct_tested = number_of_tested/len(df.index)`